# Display Image from folder while the path is in Database In RDLC Report

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rdlc

How to Show Pictures of students which is located in folder and the path is in database But I'm unable to Do it I Searched a lot but found nothing useful.
Please help me guys

[image]
[image: I am getting like this]

```
            protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                string query = @"select StudentID,c.DocumentType as DocumentID,DocumentNumber,Name,NameDari,FatherName,FatherNameDari,MobileNumber,Photo,b.ClassName as ClassID,d.LocationName as LocationID,e.TeacherName as TeacherID,a.Term,a.Score from StudentsInfo a 
join Class b 
on a.ClassID=b.ClassID
join Document c
on c.DocumentID=a.DocumentID
join Location d
on d.LocationID=a.LocationID
join Teachers e
on e.TeacherID=a.TeacherID";
                var data = db.Database.SqlQuery<StudentsInfo>(query);
                ReportViewer1.SizeToReportContent = true;
                ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("Certificates.rdlc");

                ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
                ReportDataSource ds = new ReportDataSource("Certificates", data);
                ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(ds);
                this.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.EnableExternalImages = true;
                ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
            }

        }
```

Comment: Can you provide how photo/image path value from DB looks like? If it contains absolute path, you can just include it by expression, otherwise you need to set a report parameter for destination path and combine all in expression.

Comment: It Contains only few paths like Project/photos/ImageName.jpg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, make sure that you're already done these steps in RDLC report designer:

**1)** Set "External" mode from image source property.

**2)** Create a report parameter to hold inserted path from code behind by using `Add Parameter` from context menu.

Then, you can try example below after enabling `EnableExternalImages`:

```
this.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.EnableExternalImages = true;

/* begin added part */

// get absolute path to Project folder
string path = new Uri(Server.MapPath("~/path/to/Project/folder")).AbsoluteUri; // adjust path to Project folder here

// set above path to report parameter
var parameter = new ReportParameter[1];
parameter[0] = new ReportParameter("ImagePath", path); // adjust parameter name here
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(parameter);
/* end of added part */

ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
```

Then in report expression editor, define simple expression that concatenates inserted path from `ReportParameter` and stored path from database (here the parameter name should match with `ReportParameter` in example code above):

```
=Parameters!ImagePath.Value + Fields!Photo.Value
```

References:

- [How to add an external image in RDLC Report (C#)](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d1acbabc-4181-43ee-b9c6-795d99ecdbac/how-to-add-an-external-image-in-rdlc-report-c?forum=csharpgeneral)
- [Dynamically add and display external Image in RDLC Report from code behind in ASP.Net](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Dynamically-add-and-display-external-Image-in-RDLC-Report-from-code-behind-in-ASPNet.aspx)